# Should I award my bounty if no new answer was provided?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently created a bounty for 
[What is AMP HTML and how does it fit in with framework/tool X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999561/what-is-amp-html-and-how-does-it-fit-in-with-framework-tool-x). No one responded with any new answers; only the existing, incomplete, answer remains.

What am I supposed to do here? I don't want to award an answer that wasn't good enough before the bounty.

Comment: Hmm...`Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦`.

Comment: However, I'd suggest that don't award an answer that wasn't good enough, and start another bounty, explain why do you want start another one and didn't award your previous bounty in bounty comment, and see if the answerer updated his answer or there's other answers.

Comment: You don't have to award the bounty if you don't want to. However, *if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).*

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I will award anything based on what is being said here. I feel like the rep points should go back to you if no new answers are provided.

Comment: This has come up before, so rather than hash it out again here I suggest a search on Meta, but to sum it up: _"I feel like the rep points should go back to you if no new answers are provided."_ You don't pay for an _answer,_ you pay for _attention._ You got the attention, it's just no one gave you an answer. Would a newspaper refund your money if no one responded to the ad you paid for?

Comment: @Kendra - I think you misunderstand what StackOverflow is. I was trying to get an example of how we, as a community of developers, should use Google's AMP spec in a production project - and I put the bounty on someone else's question. Perhaps, if I had some weird super specific coding problem that only applied to my work your analogy would be right but it's wrong in this context.

Comment: No, in the way that bounties work, that is a correct analogy. You paid for attention to the question. That payment did not receive any interested (or more likely, able) answerers. You paid for the question to get eyeballs on it. Stack Overflow does not refund your payment, as you still received the extra attention on the question, whether the question was yours, mine, or Joe Random's.

Comment: From the help center: _"Part of what you’re “paying for” with the bounty is to get additional attention for your question, over and beyond what a normal question gets. A bounty does not guarantee a response, however, and reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty."_ From [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/266735): _"Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher question visibility and increased answerer motivation."_ (The "What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?" section.)